# script to find and replace lines with sed?

Tags: python, c++

I have try to create script to find some line from all files and replace it with other line but does't work. This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/home/Desktop

WGETCHANGE='$WGET -q -O $FreeServertmpa74 $(<freeservrb79)'
REPLACECURL='curl -k $(<freeservrb79) -o $FreeServertmpa74 > /de/null/ 2>&1'

for l in `find /"${D}$PATH" \( -name "*control" -o -name "*.sh"-o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.pp" \)`
        do
             sed -i "s/$WGETCHANGE/$REPLACECURL/g" "$l"
        done

exit 0
```

Comment: Neither of your tags seem relevant. How about using the `bash` and `sed` tags instead?

Comment: No good idea: `PATH=/home/Desktop` From `man bash`: `The search path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands`

Comment: `does't work` is the worst possible problem description as it tells us nothing about the problem you're asking for help with. Do you get no output, wrong output, error messages, core dumps, something else? Please [edit] your question to provide that missing information and concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled '/dev/null', which isn't the problem but is related to the problem.

I think the problem is that you have '/dev/null' at all, because you're using '/' as your substitute delimiter.  The sed command becomes:

```
sed -i 's/$WGET -q -O $FreeServertmpa74 $(<freeservrb79)/curl -k $(<freeservrb79) -o $FreeServertmpa74 > /de/null/ 2>&1/g'
```

Because '/' is the delimiter after 's', sed is trying to replace

```
$WGET -q -O $FreeServertmpa74 $(<freeservrb79)
```

with

```
curl -k $(<freeservrb79) -o $FreeServertmpa74 >
```

and it's reading 'de' as options to the 's' instruction.

The easiest fix is to use a different delimiter, such as a colon:

```
sed -i "s:$WGETCHANGE:$REPLACECURL:g" "$l"
```

(You can use anything for the delimiter after 's' except for backslash and newline.)

Comment: Thank you ... Works just fine with me